# how to show cubic function is one to one using assumption

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Okay I know the function $f(x)= x^3 +2x+3$ is one to one but how do I show that using the assumption that $f(a)=f(b)$ where $a=b$?

So if I do the process I have

$ a^3+2a+3 = b^3+2b+3$ my 3's cancel and i get

$a^3+2a= b^3+2b$

I know I can factor out an $a$ and $b$

$a(a^2+2)=b(b^2+2)$

but what do I do from here to show $a=b$?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that

$$a^3+2a= b^3+2b\iff a^3-b^3+2(a-b)=0\iff (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2+2)=0...(1)$$

Since $$a^2+ab+b^2+2=\left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2+\frac{b^2}{4}+2\ge 2$$

it follows that the only real solution of ($1$) is $a=b$. Then $f$ is one-to-one.

---

**Another approach:**

Since $f'(x)=3x^2+2>0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ it follows $f$ is increasing, then monotone, which implies it is one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(a) = x^3 + 2x + 3$. IF $f(a) = f(b)$, you want to show that $a = b $. You can show this by contradiction. In fact, if $a \neq b$. Then, either $a > b$ or $a < b$.  Consider first case: If $a > b $. Then $2a > 2b $ and $a^3 > b^3$ since cubic function is an increasing function. Hence,

$$ f(a) = a^3 + 2a + 3 > b^3 + 2b + 3 = f(b) \implies f(a) > f(b) $$

Contradiction since we assumed $f(a) = f(b)$

Similarly, if $b > a $ we obtain $f(b) > f(a) $, which is again a contradiction. IT follows that if $f(a) = f(b) $, then $a=b$.

Comment: You really don't need to consider two cases. Just saying "Without loss of  generality take $a>b$" is sufficient.